# Creating multiple duplicates when I try and extract data from API

Tags: node.js, web-scraping

Trying to pull data from a node.js API
[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/boxing/boxrec)

But when I try and pull data based on multiple globalids (I use the global id to get output from the API), I keep getting multiple duplicates when I merge my datasets. No idea what I am doing wrong, there are no duplicates in the actual global_ids dataset, have checked multiple times

This is the code I have:

```
const boxrec = require("boxrec").Boxrec;
const fastcsv = require('fast-csv');
const fs = require('fs');
async function getCookieJar(){
    try {
        const cookieJar = await boxrec.login('**','***');
        return cookieJar;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Login error: " + e);
    }
};
async function writeData() {
    const csv = require('csv-parser')
    const results = [];
    fs.createReadStream('C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\completed16.csv')
        .pipe(csv())
        .on('data',(data)=> results.push(data))
        .on('end', async () => {
          const cookieJar = await getCookieJar();
          const promises = [];
          results.forEach((data) => {
            promises.push(boxrec.getPersonById(cookieJar,data.global_id));
          })
          const fighters = await Promise.all(promises); 
          fighters.forEach((fighter) => {
              let data = '';
              for (const key in fighter.output) {
                  if (Array.isArray(fighter.output[key])) {
                      data += JSON.stringify(fighter.output[key]) + ',';
                  } else if (typeof fighter.output[key] === 'object') {
                      data += JSON.stringify(fighter.output[key]) + ',';
                  } else {
                      data += fighter.output[key] + ',';
                  }
              }
              data = data.replace(/(^,)|(,$)/g, "");
              data += '\n';

              fs.appendFile('C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\fin16.csv',data, (err) => {
                  if (err) throw err;
              });
          });
        });
    };
try {
    writeData();
} catch (error) {
    console.log("Error in writeData: " + error);
```

Here is a sample of the data from completed16:

[image: sample of dataset]

Not every row is duplicated, but for exampled completed6 has 100 unique globalIDs, the output created will contain 100 rows but some global ids are duplicated multiple times (as much as 13 times for certain global_Ids.

I have emailed the author of the API and he thinks the problems might be occurring when I write my data to a csv

Comment: Just an observation: When you attach the 'data' event listener, you receive chunks of data (https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_data). But for each of those chunks (whose size and structure you don't know in advance), you are calling a function (`getPersonById`) as if you had 1 row of the input spreadsheet. I'd expect some calls to fail, so I'm a bit surprised.

Comment: @sturmer what would you suggest I do?

Comment: Not sure. You should somehow make sure that an entire row is available. What do you see if you print the chunk at each `data` event? Maybe when you receive one containing `\n` you can process the row?